# JS - Detect Appium click on a webView in Android

Tags: javascript, android, automation, appium

I'm looking for a JS way to detect if a click (on a WebView) was emulated by an automated test. Reading this [stack-overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) about selenium detection was my initial starting point.

I've created a simple Appium test:

```
driver.init({
    browserName: '',
    'appium-version': '1.8.1',
    platformName: 'Android',
    device:"Android",
    deviceName: 'Android'
    app: "path/to/my.apk"
  }).catch((e)=>{
    console.error("ERROR",e);
  }).setImplicitWaitTimeout(3000).then(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("Clicking");
      let webView = driver.elementByClassName("android.webkit.WebView",()=>{});
      webView.click();
    },3000);
  });
```

The only thing I could spot was that clientX, clientY on the JS event was always the same. I assume there is a way to emulate different x and y by code.

So my question is: Is there a way to detect Appium using only the JS running in the WebView?

Comment: you could check the touch radius too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/radiusX